# how to assign comment count to post using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below works fine and display post record successfully.
No I want to get the comment count for each post based on post (pid).

I have implemented this function below

```
getCounterByPid(pid)
```

**My issue:** The function above display comment counting **3** for each post.

Normally, the post with pid 102 should show 2 comment count, then others 1 count each

**here is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {

//function Application() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

post: {"results": 
[
{"desc": "my first product", "pid": "101"},
{"desc": "my second product", "pid": "102"},
{"desc": "my 3rd product", "pid": "103"},

]},


comment: {"res": 
[
{"comment": "hello 1", "pid": "101"},
{"comment": "hello 2", "pid": "102"},
{"comment": "hello 3", "pid": "103"},
{"comment": "hello 4", "pid": "102"},

]},

    };

  }


// get total comment count for each post
 getCounterByPid(pid) {
const resIndex = this.state.comment.res.findIndex(el => pid === el.pid);
//const c1 = this.state.comment.res[resIndex].counting;

const comment_count = this.state.comment.res[resIndex].pid;
const comment_l = comment_count.length;

//alert(comment_count.length);


return comment_l;
  };



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.post.results.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.pid} - {obj.desc}<br />

 <span> Comment count: ({this.getCounterByPid(obj.pid)})</span>


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code:

```
const resIndex = this.state.comment.res.findIndex(el => pid === el.pid);
    //const c1 = this.state.comment.res[resIndex].counting;

    const comment_count = this.state.comment.res[resIndex].pid;
    const comment_l = comment_count.length;
```

`findIndex` will find one of the comments in your array, it doesn't matter which it returns but it will return an index.

`comment_count` however will be the actual pid of that comment so `101`, `102` or `103` depending on the value of `findIndex`

Finally, you are returning the length of that pid, which will always be 3.

---

Rather than do that, you can just filter the comments to find all the comments which are related to that specific pid. Then return the length of that filtered array.

```
  getCounterByPid(pid) {
    const comments = this.state.comment.res.filter(el => pid === el.pid);
    return comments.length;
  }
```

I have created a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sunset-szn6t